# What does "Kantenblatt" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does "Kantenblatt" mean? I did not find it in a dictionary. I know that "Blatt" is a kind of list.

Comment: In which kontext? In Gnome it could be `Edge Flipping` in botany it a part of cypress leaf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Kantenblatt* ist ein Begriff aus der Architektur. Es bezeichnet ein Ornament wie es zum Beispiel auf folgender Abbildung eines frühgotischen Säulensockels zu sehen ist:

[image: Kantenblatt]

[Quelle](http://www.pictokon.net/bilder/bilder-1-2011/architektur-baustil-08-fruehgothischer-saeulensockel-mit-kantenblatt.html).

Erwähnt wird der Begriff auch im [Ökonomischen Reallexikon](http://books.google.it/books?id=ayZAAAAAcAAJ&dq=Kantenblatt&pg=PA176#v=onepage&q=Kantenblatt&f=false) aus dem Jahr 1796:

> Blatt an der Ecke, Kantenblatt, ist in der Baukunst eine Verzierung von Blättern an den Ecken oder Kanten der Glieder des Gebälks der Kapitäler einer Säulenordnung von Bildhauer- oder Stukaturarbeit, um das Gesimse zu beschließen.

[image: Kantenblatt Definition]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know German.

Comment: @Anixx: _Kantenblatt_ ("edge-leaf") is a term from architecture. It means a leaf-shaped ornament on a pillar's base, like the one shown in the illustration above.